# PHP goes on infinite loop

Tags: php, infinite-loop

This code goes on a infinite loop and gives me a

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of
>   30 seconds exceeded

This is the code i am using

```
<?php 
$sofar = 1;

while ($sofar == 1);
{
echo $sofar;
$sofar == $sofar+1;
}

?>
```

Comment: just a jump start for you why not try echo $sofar == $sofar+1; and see what happens =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is using two equal signs for the increment. Ie `$sofar = $sofar + 1` is correct but you have `$sofar ==` instead. Alternatively  just `$sofar++` or `++$sofar` works.

your basically doing

```
if($sofar == $sofar+1){/*Nothing*/}
```

so your expression would evaluate to

```
if(1 == 2){/*nothing*/}
```

There for $sofar never cahnges, you have to use `=` to change or set the value of a variable.

your also adding a semi-colon at the end of your `while` statement, The semicolon signifies the end of a PHP statement.

You should be doing

```
if( condition )
{

}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work:<?php 
$sofar = 1;

while ($sofar == 1);
{
echo $sofar;
$sofar = $sofar+1;
}

?>

Comment: Remove the semi colon. from after `while()`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$sofar = 1;

while ($sofar == 1)
{
echo $sofar;
$sofar = $sofar+1;
}

?>
```

You have one = sign too many

And you have an ; after your while.

One = sign assign value
Two == signs compare values

You could also use:

```
$sofar++;
$sofar += 1;
$sofar = $sofar +1;
```

Or perhaps:

```
$sofar = 1;

while ($sofar == 1)
{
    echo ++$sofar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely, it should be:

```
$sofar = $sofar + 1
```

rather than

```
$sofar == $sofar + 1
```

The latter one (which you are using) is a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your using `==` which is not an assignment operator but a conditional operators.

you should be doing `$sofar = $sofar+1;` or `$sofar++;` to increment the value

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$sofar = 1;

while ($sofar == 1) {
  echo $sofar;
  $sofar++;
}
?>
```

Increment with `++`.

Answer (score 0):

`==` is a [comparison operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), not [assigment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) (`=`) so that instruction `$sofar == $sofar+1;` actually doesn't do anything (it returns `false` to nowhere).

In other words: `$sofar` is always `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon at the end of your `while` statement.  This is equivalent to

```
while ($sofar == 1) {

}
```

and will therefore result in an infinite loop.  Also, you are doing a comparison, not an assignment.  Your code should look like this:

```
<?php 
$sofar = 1;

while ($sofar == 1)
{
echo $sofar;
$sofar = $sofar+1;
}

?>
```